# How can I get a list of variable names from a lark-parser Tree?

Tags: python-3.x, lark-parser

I am using python 3.8.5 and lark-parser 0.11.2.  I have a question about Visitors.

I have a grammar for my needs and Lark is working great.  I have a case where,
under some conditions, I want to evaluate a returned parse tree and scan it to
get a, possibly empty, list of variable names appearing in the tree.

A sample expression is:

```
count + num_items
```

The parse tree from the expression is:

```
Tree('add', [Tree('variable', [Token('VARIABLE', 'count')]), Tree('variable', [Token('VARIABLE', 'num_items')])])
```

I figured that I would write a Visitor class that would scann the tree for variables and store them in an internal list:

```
from lark import Visitor, v_args
@v_args(inline=True)
class FindVariables(Visitor):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.variable_list = []

    def variable(self, var):
        try:
            self.variable_list.append(var)
        except Exception as e:
            raise
```

I am trying to use it as:

```
fv = FindVariables()
fv2 = fv.visit(parse_result)
for var in fv.variable_list:
    ...
```

The issue I have is that when `fv = FindVariables()` is executed I get a
`TypeError` exception:

```
f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

If I change the call above to:

```
fv = FindVariables().visit(parse_result)
```

the statement runs but `fv` does not "see" `variable_list`.

I am probably misusing the Visitor class.  Is there a best/better way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am answering my question but I am not sure that it is *the* answer.

I changed `Visitor` to `Transformer` in the code block in the question and it just worked.

I am glad that I have a solution but it *feels* like `Visitor` should have been the right tool here. Still happy to find out if I am misusing the lib here and if there is a better way.